# kivymd Card scroll list items with the help of loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, kivy, kivymd

I am working on a mobile app and I want to create multiple of scoll items by using for loop but whenever I use `for loop`, gives me some error `It has already parent widget`. how can I make list of `MDCard`?

**My App*:*
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j610B.png)

**My Code:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

Window.size = (450, 740)

kv = '''
ScreenManager:
    Main:

<main>:
    name: 'main'
    video_list: video_list
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Video downloader'

        ScrollView:
            Screen:
                id: video_list
     '''

class Main(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Main(name='main'))

class Ytube(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.colors = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)

        image = AsyncImage(
            source='https://static.hub.91mobiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/How-to-download-youtube-videos.jpg', size_hint=(1, .7), )
        screen_id = self.root.get_screen('main').ids.video_list

        for i in range(1):
            card = MDCard(orientation='vertical', pos_hint={
                            'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}, size_hint=(.9, .4))
            card.add_widget(image)
            card.add_widget(MDLabel(
                text='Phishing attacks are SCARY easy to do!! (let me show you!)', size_hint=(.6, .2), ))
            screen_id.add_widget(card)

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ytube().run()
```

Is there any way to make it
[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXden.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the same `image` widget for every `MDCard`. Any widget can only have one parent. You can only use that `image` widget once. You can fix that by moving the creation of the `image` widget inside the loop.

Also, a `BoxLayout` is a better choice for the child of a `ScrollView`, since it has a `minimum_height` property that you can use. Here is a modified version of your code that applies both those suggestions:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

Window.size = (450, 740)

kv = '''
ScreenManager:
    Main:

<main>:
    name: 'main'
    video_list: video_list
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Video downloader'

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            BoxLayout:
                id: video_list
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
     '''

class Main(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Main(name='main'))

class Ytube(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.colors = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)

        screen_id = self.root.get_screen('main').ids.video_list

        for i in range(5):
            # Make a new image widget for each MDCard
            image = AsyncImage(
                source='https://static.hub.91mobiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/How-to-download-youtube-videos.jpg', size_hint=(1, .7), )
            card = MDCard(orientation='vertical', pos_hint={
                            'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}, size_hint=(.9, None), height=200)
            card.add_widget(image)
            card.add_widget(MDLabel(
                text='Phishing attacks are SCARY easy to do!! (let me show you!)', size_hint=(.6, .2), ))
            screen_id.add_widget(card)

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ytube().run()
```